# Custom Attribute Named Arguments Not Populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, reflection, attributes

I have made an custom attribute, but I want to be able to pass a named arguments with it.

Here is the attribute below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AnyAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    public AnyAuthorizeAttribute()
        : base(typeof(AnyAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        var roles = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles) ? Roles.Split(", ") : new string[0];

        Arguments = new[] { roles };
    }
}

    [HttpGet("roles/{id:int}", Name = "GetRole")]
    [AnyAuthorize(Roles = "Administrator, Super User")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_unitOfWork.Roles.Exists(id))
            {
                return BadRequest("No role exists with the id supplied");
            }
```

Everything looks alright to me, but every time I run it, the Roles property is equal to null.
Any normal parameters I user with the attribute look fine.

I am using this in asp.net core 2.2

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you getting an instance of the attribute? Can you share your code (as text, **not** a screenshot) including the bit where you end up with an instance of the attribute to inspect?

Comment: Please, do not post code as images. And the example usage of this attribute

Comment: The `Roles` property isn't assigned until after the attribute's constructor returns, same as an object initializer.

Comment: I tested your code and searched many hours, but never seen someone to use named parameter for CustomAttributes that inherit from TypeFilterAttribute.They just use constructor parameter.In your case AnyAuthorizeAttribute(string roles) : base(typeof(AnyAuthorizeAttribute)) would work.

Comment: @WaiHaLee -Pavel Anikhouski- You're both absolutely right. I apologies, should have added it as a snippet.

I am using this attribute for a controller method/endpoint

I have tried doing the same with just inheriting from and Attribute instead of TypeFilterAttribute, but it has the same issue.

Again it just returns null....

-madreflections- is there anything I can do to get it to work there?